# ML5 can't train XOR

Tags: javascript, machine-learning

```js
// dataset
{ a: 0, b: 0, output: 'zero' },
{ a: 1, b: 0, output: 'one' },
{ a: 0, b: 1, output: 'one' },
{ a: 1, b: 1, output: 'zero' },

const options : {
  task: 'regression',
};

// outputs
// 0,0 => zero
// 1,0 => one
// 0,1 => one
// 1,1 => one
```

I'm not able to figure out what is going on, the learning process seems to be successfull.

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ut9iyb?file=App.tsx

---

*Edit: to the guy voting to close for "needs detail or clarity", tell me what information do you need, you have access to the code, even a repro, the problem is clear and explained in a sentence of only 4 words, if it's beyond your knowledge just move on to the next question but don't vote to close, that's stupid.*